# What does Configure RESET Port Pin as wire-AND mean?

Tags: atmega, atmega328p

[image]I am studying to use the ATmega328P in debug mode and this sentence in the datasheet is confusing especially the term "wire-AND".

Link to Datasheet-https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf

Chapter 22

Section 22.3

Comment: Please [edit], add a link to the datasheet and give page or chapter reference so we don't have to search through hundreds of pages.

Comment: The DS reads "wire-and (open-drain)". Open drain is pretty easy to look up.

Comment: What does the sentence say? Which particular sentence? Copy and paste an image maybe?

Comment: Typically, wire-and-ing (also wire-or-ing, depending upon what is considered a "1") is a configuration where a signal line (your input) is pulled up by a resistor, and pulled down by any number of open-collector or open drain outputs connected to that signal line. The signal line will be high if and only if all of the open collectors/drains are in their off (non-conducting) state. The pull-up resistor may be an external component, or it may be internal to your device.

Comment: It would be insightful if someone can answer why the data sheet specifically mentions 'wire-AND' instead of simply 'open-drain'.